# Symfony3 - Getting service into entity

Tags: php, symfony, dry, symfony-3.4

I'm currently working with Symfony 3.4.

I've read that it's not recommanded to get a service into an entity class. Why ?

Imagine that we have a method saveFile() in this entity class. Exceptions can be thrown in this method so we put a try/catch block and in the catch block we want to log the exception. To log exception we need to use the logger service but we can't because it's not recommended.
So finally we have to move try/catch block into controller to get the service in catch block. We have to do this each time we call saveFile() method in controller. Is it not repeatitive ? What about DRY ?

What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a subscriber/listener and listen to  `kernel.exception` event?

Comment: Probably, it is opinion based, but method that saves file - __saves file__. It doesn't care who will process error during saving. Method just says "hey, here's an error, somebody do something". So, we come to single responsibility principle - class saves file, it's not class's responsibility to write to log.

Comment: Actually, you should have in your entity getFile/setFile, method saveFile should be in service as saveFile(YourEntity $entity) or just file as parameter and $entity->getUploadedFile(). Maybe two fields - uploadedFile and File, where file is column and uploadedFile not. So you have your upload service, which has logger servie

Comment: @Eakethet is right I reckon, have a look there https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Comment: @Eakethet Thanks for the good idea. I do not have the reflex yet to create service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony uses Doctrine.

Doctrine implements the "Data Mapper" design pattern.

This is different to the "Active Record" pattern which would implement the behaviour you describe, that is `$myEntity->save()`.

The key difference in this respect is that in a data mapper pattern the entities only describe the structure of the data they represent.

They know nothing about the method by which they are transposed into any data storage.

This is handled, in doctrine's case, by the entity manager, which will take a given entity object and map it to a row in the database.

This approach achieves a level of separation between the logic that stores / retrieves data and the constructs that hold it within the model level of your application.

So, the reason you don't typically put services or db calls or whatever into your entities is because the approach is typically the other way around in that the entity is passed to services which then go off and do stuff with it.

Have a look here for some abstract info about data mappers in PHP: https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Structural/DataMapper/README.html

Also helpful: https://www.culttt.com/2014/06/18/whats-difference-active-record-data-mapper/

Comment: I'm coming from Yii framework which is using Active Record pattern. Now I have understand how to get thing done correcty with services in Symfony. Thanks for your clear answer and your links about Design patterns.